automate the drawing of angles in 3d perspective
Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727949/319072
Is  there a way to automate the drawing of angles in 3d perspective? The angles library just draws them on the screen plane. I can do it manually, but the process is extremely time consuming.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pa{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pc{1}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qa{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\ra{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rb{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\pa-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\pb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\pc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpl{sqrt((\qpa)^2 + (\qpb)^2 + (\qpc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\qpa/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\qpb/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\qpc/\qpl}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\ra-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\rb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\rc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrl{sqrt((\qra)^2 + (\qrb)^2 + (\qrc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\qra/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\qrb/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\qrc/\qrl}

    \tdplotcrossprod(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\za{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zb{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zc{\tdplotresz}
    
    \coordinate (P) at (\pa,\pb,\pc);
    \coordinate (Q) at (\qa,\qb,\qc);
    \coordinate (R) at (\ra,\rb,\rc);
    \coordinate (QP) at (\qpa,\qpb,\qpc);
    \coordinate (QR) at (\qra,\qrb,\qrc);
    \coordinate (Z) at (\za,\zb,\zc);

    \draw[<->] (P) -- (Q) -- (R);
    \begin{scope}[
    x={(QP)}, y={(QR)}, z={(Z)}, 
    canvas is xy plane at z=0
    ]
    \draw[red] ($(Q) + (QP)$) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1];
    \draw pic[draw,blue,-, angle radius=1cm,]{angle=R--Q--P};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Use transform shape as in \draw pic[draw, blue, angle radius=1cm, transform shape] {angle=P--Q--R};.

You can make use of the transform shape option:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pa{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pc{1}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qa{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\ra{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rb{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\pa-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\pb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\pc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpl{sqrt((\qpa)^2 + (\qpb)^2 + (\qpc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\qpa/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\qpb/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\qpc/\qpl}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\ra-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\rb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\rc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrl{sqrt((\qra)^2 + (\qrb)^2 + (\qrc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\qra/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\qrb/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\qrc/\qrl}

    \tdplotcrossprod(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\za{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zb{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zc{\tdplotresz}
    
    \coordinate (P) at (\pa,\pb,\pc);
    \coordinate (Q) at (\qa,\qb,\qc);
    \coordinate (R) at (\ra,\rb,\rc);
    \coordinate (QP) at (\qpa,\qpb,\qpc);
    \coordinate (QR) at (\qra,\qrb,\qrc);
    \coordinate (Z) at (\za,\zb,\zc);

    \draw[<->] (P) -- (Q) -- (R);
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(QP)}, y={(QR)}, z={(Z)}, 
        canvas is xy plane at z=0
    ]
        %\draw[red] ($(Q) + (QP)$) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1];
        \draw pic[draw, blue, angle radius=1cm, transform shape] {angle=P--Q--R};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



To automate things a bit further, you can create a custom style:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\tikzset{
    angle in plane/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{
        x={(#1)}, y={(#2)}, z={(#3)}, 
        canvas is xy plane at z=0,
        transform shape
    }
}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pa{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pc{1}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qa{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\ra{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rb{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\pa-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\pb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\pc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpl{sqrt((\qpa)^2 + (\qpb)^2 + (\qpc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\qpa/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\qpb/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\qpc/\qpl}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\ra-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\rb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\rc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrl{sqrt((\qra)^2 + (\qrb)^2 + (\qrc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\qra/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\qrb/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\qrc/\qrl}

    \tdplotcrossprod(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\za{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zb{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zc{\tdplotresz}
    
    \coordinate (P) at (\pa,\pb,\pc);
    \coordinate (Q) at (\qa,\qb,\qc);
    \coordinate (R) at (\ra,\rb,\rc);
    \coordinate (QP) at (\qpa,\qpb,\qpc);
    \coordinate (QR) at (\qra,\qrb,\qrc);
    \coordinate (Z) at (\za,\zb,\zc);

    \draw[<->] (P) -- (Q) -- (R);
    \draw pic[draw, blue, angle radius=1cm, angle in plane={QP,QR,Z}] {angle={P--Q--R}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Same output as above.
But maybe setting the perspective globally is a better approach? Something like this (but I am unsure why the perspective is different from your original code):
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\tikzset{
    xyz from points/.code args={(#1,#2,#3) (#4,#5,#6) (#7,#8,#9)}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{(#1-#4) / (sqrt((#1-#4)^2 + (#2-#5)^2 + (#3-#6)^2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{(#2-#5) / (sqrt((#1-#4)^2 + (#2-#5)^2 + (#3-#6)^2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{(#3-#6) / (sqrt((#1-#4)^2 + (#2-#5)^2 + (#3-#6)^2))}

        \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{(#7-#4) / (sqrt((#7-#4)^2 + (#8-#5)^2 + (#9-#6)^2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{(#8-#5) / (sqrt((#7-#4)^2 + (#8-#5)^2 + (#9-#6)^2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{(#9-#6) / (sqrt((#7-#4)^2 + (#8-#5)^2 + (#9-#6)^2))}
    
        \tdplotcrossprod(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)
        
        \tikzset{
            x={(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)},
            y={(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)},
            z={(\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)},
            canvas is xy plane at z=0
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tdplot_main_coords,
    xyz from points={(2,2,1) (-1,2,2) (1,-1,2)}
]
    
    \coordinate (P) at (2,0,0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (0,2,0);

    \draw[<->] (P) -- (Q) -- (R);
    \draw pic[draw, blue, angle radius=1cm, transform shape] {angle={P--Q--R}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you, is there a way to do it without specifying the unit vectors for the canvas? I don't like doing all of those calculations.

Like, could I just define three coordinates, and have the angle automatically be drawn in the plane through them?

@Jasper What about creating a custom style with x={(QP)}, y={(QR)}, z={(Z)}, canvas is xy plane at z=0, transform shape and add this as option to the pic?

Ah, I think I can use a distance modifier in tikz calc to make QP and QR unit vectors, then we wouldn't need to use so many \pgfmathsetmacros. The hard part with calculating the style is that I need to access the individual coordinate components to perform calculations on them (e.g. the cross product).

Thank you for all the work you've put into this, I'm just wondering if there is away to put all of the \pgfmathsetmacro calculations into the style or a command? It would be very tedious to calculate all of these separately for even two or three angles. An alternative solution would be to extrat 3D coordinate components, but I don't think that's possible.

@Jasper I am unsure what your aim is and I don't fully understand the calculations to be honest, but you could maybe just do the calculations in a style and set x, y and z according to the results. Then you should be able to get the unit vectors.

I set the values of the coordinate components for three coordinates, then I calculate two difference vectors using a common point, then I make these vectors unit length. I would like to be able to define three coordinates using just plain numbers, and then have the angle put between them in their plane - without having to do all of the work. Especially difficult is that in order to obtain a good (Z) coordinate, we need to use \tdplotcrossprod()(), which takes individual components. I'm going to explore some stuff with tikz calc.

There is a tikz-3dplot solution: (the thick green one is correct, though it has a dimension too large error.) See \tdplotdrawpolytopearc
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pa{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pc{1}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qa{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qb{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\ra{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rb{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rc{2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\pa-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\pb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\pc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpl{sqrt((\qpa)^2 + (\qpb)^2 + (\qpc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpa{\qpa/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpb{\qpb/\qpl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qpc{\qpc/\qpl}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\ra-\qa}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\rb-\qb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\rc-\qc}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrl{sqrt((\qra)^2 + (\qrb)^2 + (\qrc)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qra{\qra/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrb{\qrb/\qrl}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\qrc{\qrc/\qrl}

    \tdplotcrossprod(\qpa,\qpb,\qpc)(\qra,\qrb,\qrc)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\za{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zb{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zc{\tdplotresz}
    
    \coordinate (P) at (\pa,\pb,\pc);
    \coordinate (Q) at (\qa,\qb,\qc);
    \coordinate (R) at (\ra,\rb,\rc);
    \coordinate (QP) at (\qpa,\qpb,\qpc);
    \coordinate (QR) at (\qra,\qrb,\qrc);
    \coordinate (Z) at (\za,\zb,\zc);

    \draw[<->] (P) -- (Q) -- (R);
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(QP)}, y={(QR)}, z={(Z)}, 
        canvas is xy plane at z=0
    ]
        \draw[red] ($(Q) + (QP)$) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1];
        \draw pic[draw,blue,-, angle radius=1cm,]{angle=R--Q--P};
    \end{scope}
    
    %%% added
    \tdplotdefinepoints(\qa,\qb,\qc)(\pa,\pb,\pc)(\ra,\rb,\rc)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[ultra thick, green]{1}{left}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


